# Copy a file from a listbox to new folder

Tags: c#

I'm trying to cope a file from D:\Local_temp to anther folder which is in D:\Newfolder" that based on the files displayed in the listbox but I get an error that I can't solve it.
I'm using the following code:

```
DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Local_temp");
FileInfo[] files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.msg");

DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParse(this.TextBox1.Text, out dt))
{

    files.Where(x => File.GetCreationTime(x.FullName).Date == dt.Date).ToList().ForEach(x => this.ListBox1.Items.Add(x.Name));

    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Local_temp.msg")) //the error is here
        File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(@"D:\Newfolder", Path.GetFileName(file)), true);

}
```

the error is Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Local_temp.msg'.

Please help me..
Thank you..

Comment: Use the overload of `Directory.GetFiles` that takes a search pattern:  `(var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Local_temp", "*.msg")...`

Comment: I get this message (Access to the path 'D:\Newfolder\H-MSG-MSG-Disk 0-201405110430-4095.MSG' is denied.)

Comment: You need to ensure that the account the program is running under has access to that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you have a typo in your `Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Local_temp.msg")` in your `foreach`.  You probably want to use the overload that takes a search pattern, like this:

```
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Local_temp", "*.msg"))
```

The way it's currently written, you're looking for all files in the "Local_temp.msg" directory on drive letter D.

Comment: Now the problem is in this code File.Copy(file, Path.Combine(@"D:\Newfolder", Path.GetFileName(file)), true);..I get a message which is (Access to the path 'D:\Newfolder\H-MSG-MSG-Disk 0-201405110430-4095.MSG' is denied)

Comment: The account the program is running under needs to have permission to access (write to) that folder.

Comment: how can get the permission to access this folder?

Comment: Go to the folder D:\Newfolder in Windows Explorer, right click, select properties, select the Seucrity tab, click the Edit button and add the proper user account and give it read/write permissions.